# Error Failed to load resource (Action Method) on IIS server, but work successfully on localhost

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, iis-7

i am using Visual studio 2012 with EntityFramwork4.4

i have created view VoucherRaisedbyMe and in it have loading partial view in div element. partial view has webgrid and loading data in it.

its working fine with localhost but after publish on IIS7 server it shows below error for
 ActionMethod of partial view 
**Error:**

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found) http://localhost/Voucher/VoucherRaisedbyMePartial

*(view)*  **VoucherRaisedbyMe**

```
             <table><tr>
                    <td colspan="5">
                        <div id="gridContent">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnGo").click(function () {
            loadGrid();
        });           
    });
</script>
    <script>
    function loadGrid() {
        var booksDiv = $("#gridContent");
        var items = {};
        items.vFinYear = $("#ddl_FinnYear").val();
        items.vDeptCode = $("#ddl_Dept").val();
        //alert('hi');
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "/Voucher/VoucherRaisedbyMePartial",
            data: '{items: ' + JSON.stringify(items) + '}',
            success: function (data) {
                booksDiv.html('');
                booksDiv.html(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                debugger;
                alert(thrownError);
                alert('Failed to retrieve data.');
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

*(action method to call partial view)* **VoucherRaisedbyMePartial**

```
public ActionResult VoucherRaisedbyMePartial(Voucher items)
{
   var VoucherList = new List<Voucher>(); // getting proper list 
   return PartialView("_VoucherRaisedbyMePartial", VoucherList);
}
```

*(partial view*) **_VoucherRaisedbyMePartial**

```
@model IEnumerable<PVS_WEB.Models.Voucher>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "WebgridSample";
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 10, selectionFieldName: "selectedRow", ajaxUpdateContainerId: "gridContent");
    grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.NextPrevious);
}
<div id="gridContent">
    @grid.GetHtml()
</div>
```

Comment: Use `url: "@Url.Action("VoucherRaisedbyMePartial", "Voucher")",` instead

Comment: thanks a lot .... your answered worked

Answer (score 0):

Use url: "@Url.Action("VoucherRaisedbyMePartial", "Voucher")", insted

thanks haim770